# MiKTeX Update closes suddenly when updating. Why does this happen?

Tags: miktex, miktex-update

I just installed MiKTeX a while ago. I opened MiKTeX Update (Admin) and selected all the packages that came up for an update. It starts well but just closes suddenly after a while.

[image: I've selected everything and clicked Next]

I select everything and click Next

[image: Right after this, the program just closes. No error message, nothing. It doesn't finish the update either]

Right after this, the program just closes. No error message, nothing. It doesn't finish the update either

Comment: Post the Screen Shot.

Comment: You have to update the packages by clicking the Miktex Package Manager (Admin).

Comment: MiKTeX should auto-select some packages, with every update - so you should be able to just click Next without needing to select any packages, does this work?  You may need to install certain updates before others can be successfully installed.

Comment: It is auto-selecting.. That doesn't have any problems.. While installing, it just closes automatically and the update is never finished..

Comment: @DaiBowen can you help?

Comment: @Naveen let MiKTeX auto-select, and don't add any more packages to install, try running the non-admin version, try syncing with repository through the package manager first. Beyond those suggestions I have no idea I'm afraid

Comment: A work-around: download with FileZilla all recently updated files  to directory on your hard disk (including `pr.ini`, `miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma`, `miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma` and `files.csv.lzma`) and ask to update from a local repository.

Answer (score 1):

Question regarding MikTeX update problems (or install problems) appear here from time to time. Like clockwork.

I suggest the following general-purpose solution: Use MikTeX "portable" version, rather than the installer.

The portable version is installed to your user home directory, where you do not need administrative privileges. That avoids one group of installer problems.

Once you get it working, make a zip archive of the entire installation for safe-keeping. Then, if some future update causes a problem, you can discard the installation, and revert to the un-zipped, known-good installation.

If the previously known-good installation fails (without update), then that suggests Windows has altered something in the operating system. If so, that's a problem; you will have to wait until MikTeX catches up. But I do not know of any occasion where this has happened.

There is still the possibility that an anti-virus program may object to some files.

Answer (score 0):

I found sort of a tedious workaround for this.. Every time the Update manager closed, I unselected that particular package which was being installed when I retry the next time around.. I still don't know how to install these left out packages though.. At least I got to update the rest..

Comment: I had no problem to update. Perhaps you have some overeager virus protection. You could try to update with mpm on the command line. https://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/mpm.html